# Android Studio Debbuger ver contenido de un Cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy debbugeando una aplicacion y necesitaria saber en que rama entrar para ver el contenido de cuando se llama a Cursor.getString(int);[image: Atributos de Cursor durante el Debugg]

Para ver si me esta agarrando algo de mi Base de datos y si lo agarra corroborar que sea lo que estoy buscando!
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sería crear `int` de tus columnas:

```
 int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Columna_ID);
 int tituloIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Columna_Titulo);
```

Luego creas un `ArrayList` String, el `cursor` lee la base de datos
y los agrega al arraylist

```
 ArrayList<String> miArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        miArrayList.add(cursor.getString(tituloIndex)); // ó idIndex
    }
```

Y lo muestras en el LogCat:

```
 Log.i("MIRA_ARRAY", String.valueOf(miArrayList));  // muestra todos
 Log.i("MIRA_UNO", String.valueOf(miArrayList.get(0)));  // muestra solo el primero
```

Comment: Es lo que habia pensado yo pero a lo que me referia es a lo siguiente: 
Cuando tu debuggeas un programa orientado a objetos, en una especie de consola te aparecen tus objetos en ese momento del debugg en forma de "Raices" con el nombre de cada variable, que tienen una flecha, y si pinchas en la flecha se abre dicha "Raiz" y te muestra los atributos del objeto, como se muestra en la imagen que subi en la pregunta original, yo he abierto mi "Raiz" c, y queria saber si moviendome directamente en ese lugar se podrian ver los valores que lleva internamente luego de realizada la consulta.

Comment: no se ve bien la imagen

Comment: La abriste en una pestaña nueva? es 1920x1080 dudo que no se vea bien